# I can't understand pine script (over 3000 order)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

So i'm quite new to pine and trying to wrap my head around it

I don't know how to take the entry price of the long order i'm setting so I tried this but I get improper results, I assume because average position price keeps changing while longcond is true

````
strategy("wtf", overlay = true, initial_capital = 100)

ema50 = ema(close, 50)
ema200 = ema(close, 200)

plot(ema50)
plot(ema200)

TP = 0.0
SL = 0.0

longCond = (ema50 > ema200)
if (longCond)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    TP := strategy.position_avg_price * 1.2
    SL := strategy.position_avg_price * 0.8
    

strategy.exit("close", "long", limit = TP, stop = SL)```

how can I set an order and take the entry price to then set a limit and stop order for TP and SL
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default strategy orders will be placed when a bar opens. You can compare `strategy.position_size` with its previous value to figure out if you have opened a new long position and store the open price.

```
//@version=5
strategy("wtf", overlay = true, initial_capital = 100)

ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
ema200 = ta.ema(close, 200)

TP = 0.0
SL = 0.0

longCond = (ema50 > ema200)

if (longCond)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    TP := strategy.position_avg_price * 1.2
    SL := strategy.position_avg_price * 0.8

var buyPrice = 0.0
buyPrice := ta.valuewhen((strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1]), open, 0)

strategy.exit("close", "long", limit = TP, stop = SL)
plot(buyPrice)
```

[image]